# Kotlin - determine nested generic types at runtime

Tags: kotlin

I have the following classes in my solution

```kotlin
open class State<T : Any> { ... }

class CustomState : State<BigDecimal> { ... }

abstract class FindState<T : State<*>> { ... }

class FindStateImpl<T : State<*>> : FindState<T>() { ... }
```

`FindState` may be called like so

```kotlin
val strState = FindStateImpl<State<String>>(...)

val intState = FindStateImpl<State<Int>>(...)

val customState = FindStateImpl<CustomState>(...)
```

From inside the `FindState` class I need to be able to obtain at runtime, the the class types for:

- `T` in `FindState<T : State<*>>` which will be `State` or derivatives thereof.
- `T` in `State`

Thus for the examples above I would need to obtain:

```kotlin
val strState = FindStateImpl<State<String>>(...)
//State::class.java
//String::class.java

val intState = FindStateImpl<State<Int>>(...)
//State::class.java
//Int::class.java

val customState = FindStateImpl<CustomState>(...)
//CustomState::class.java
//BigDecimal::class.java (since string is the underlying type T)
```

So far I've got something like this, but it's hideous and doesn't fully work:

```kotlin
val stateType = javaClass.kotlin.supertypes[0].arguments[0].type?.jvmErasure?.javaObjectType
```

Is it possible to obtain these types at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as you've provided simply doesn't contain the type information required since it will be erased. Only the subtypes that specify a specific type as part of the supertype are available.

With kotlin there are two ways to retrieve the type information:

1. Use a pattern like Guava's `TypeToken` and make sure you provide an anonymous object that contains the required type information. This will make the reflection code work.
2. Use a reified method and the `typeOf<T>()` method to embed the `KType` during compilation:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any, CS : State<T>> FindStateEmbedType(state: CS): FindState<CS> {
    val contentType = typeOf<T>();
    // Do what you need to do with T, perhaps embed in a wrapper FindState type
    return FindStateImplWithType(state, contentType)
}
```

Comment: There is a great read why we have generics in this form on a JVM https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/erasure.html

Comment: @szymon_prz It's a shame there's no comments section on that page…  Even if you accept all the justifications there for the decisions made nearly two decades ago (and some of them do make a lot of sense), it doesn't necessarily justify what's been done _since_ to reduce some of that pain (i.e.: nothing).

Comment: @gidds yeah, we know that this subject left behind for now and we don't have any other improvements, but we received a lot of other improvements in other areas, because next improvements in generics are not us much needed and required by community and corporates as other parts of the JVM or Java, and I'm sure that You also are happy with some improvements made after generics :)